# Importing Angular component in new Stackblitz standalone Angular starter

Tags: angular, typescript, stackblitz

Stackblitz has defaulted their Angular starters to opt-in to the new standalone Angular components. With this change, I'm encountering issues importing my custom component (`FirstComponent`) into their new "main" component declared in `main.ts`.

This is my simple custom component -

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-first',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  templateUrl: './first.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./first.component.css'],
})
export class FirstComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

I've added the `standalone` and `imports` properties in the selector, but that didn't help.

Here is their `main.ts` -

```js
import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>
    <app-first></app-first>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

This is the error -

```
Error in src/main.ts (15:5)
'app-first' is not a known element:
1. If 'app-first' is an Angular component, then verify that it is included in the '@Component.imports' of this component.
2. If 'app-first' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@Component.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

Here is the stackblitz URL - https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-2hwyyr?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Answer (score 0):

With standalone components, instead of importing `NgModule`s into other `NgModule`s, you are now able to import components directly into other components (providing both are `standalone: true`).

In this case you just need to make sure you import your `FirstComponent` class into the `App` component's `imports` list:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FirstComponent
  ],
  template: `
    <h1>Hello from {{name}}!</h1>
    <a target="_blank" href="https://angular.io/start">
      Learn more about Angular 
    </a>
    <app-first></app-first>
  `,
})
export class App {
  name = 'Angular';
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-gtdpfc?file=src%2Fmain.ts